# Control event not firing from class linked to resource dictionary wpf

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, uicontrolevents

Hi I am attempting to attach a function to text box used for entering some input information which is loaded to an interface from resource dictionary. Here is the XML,

```
          <ContentControl>
            <Grid>
                <Image s:DesignerItem.Code ="1773"  IsHitTestVisible="False" Stretch="Fill" Source="../Images/addition.png"  ToolTip="Addition" />
                <TextBox Height="57" Width="56" Margin="13,13,130,13" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="45" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextChanged="msg_TextChange" KeyUp="msg_MouseDown"/>
                <TextBox Height="57" Width="56" Margin="132,13,12,13" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="45" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" KeyDown="msg_MouseDown"/>
                <Button MouseDown="msg" Width="50" Height="20">ck</Button>
            </Grid>
           </ContentControl>
```

From the above code, I attempted to use a few different types of control events. I successfully linked the class my functions are going to be placed in using the following lines to link the class to the resource dictionary.

```
 x:Class="DiagramDesigner.CodeBuilding"
 x:ClassModifier="public"
```

Here is the code for the class I am using,

```
 public partial class CodeBuilding : ResourceDictionary
{
   public CodeBuilding()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   } 

   public void msg_TextChange(object sender,EventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("oh no, you've got me ...");
   }

   public void msg(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("oh no, you've got me ...");
   }
}
```

As you can see, I am just using a simple message to indicate if the event has been fired, the project successfully builds and runs fine, but when I attempt to trigger any of the 
events used in the XML the function tied to the event does not fire at all.

I am not certain if this is the best method of linking a function to an event loaded by a resource dictionary, but can anyone provide some guidance to this problem I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

XAML file should be dependent on its partial code behind file for events to work.

Make sure **Build Action for code behind file** is set as `Compile`.

Also open your `.csproj` file in notepad or in any text editor and make sure `DepedentUpon` attribute is set on XAML file. It will look like this:

```
<Compile Include="CodeBuilding.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>CodeBuilding.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

---

On a side note, simple steps to make it work like that are:

1. Add a blank `UserControl` in your project. It will automatically do this work for you which I mentioned above.
2. All you need to do is simply change the XAML file to `ResourceDictionary`. (Replace UserControl to ResourceDictionary).
3. And in code behind just change the base class from `UserControl` to `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: Hi Rohit, I attempted this solution you presented, but the function was not called. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I added the second solution as an add on to the project I am working on and it still didn't fire any message window :(.

Comment: `ContentControl` doesn't have an `x:Key` associated with it. How are you referring it in your XAML file? Can you post small sample replicating an issue?

Comment: The control content does not have a key, but it is wrapped in another tag that has a key attached to it, here is what it looks like. `<s:Toolbox x:Key="test" ItemSize="60,50" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ItemsControl.Items>
            <ContentControl>
                ....
            </ContentControl>
        </ItemsControl.Items>
    </s:Toolbox>`

Comment: I meant can you try producing in small sample this scenario because when i tried with simple button and hook its click event, it works completely fine for me..!!

Comment: Rohit, thanks for all the time and assistance you have provided, but I cant seem to get the function to hook to control events :(. I would really liked to defer this to a chat, but that is presently beyond my capabilities.

Comment: Try to replicate same issue in small sample because it works. Refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21709570/632337) which was working for the OP.